# Fans spin constantly when charger plugged in on Asus ROG gl553vd

Tags: asus, overheating, fan

In my Asus ROG [gl-553vd](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ROG-GL553VD/HelpDesk/) laptop, the fan spins constantly when the charger is connected, even if the CPU usage is 2%-5%.

I tried the laptop battery mode tool, and now in battery mode fan speed is normal.

Logs now show
CPU0: Core temperature above threshold
CPU clock throttled (total events = 14960)
CPU1: Package temperature above threshold
CPU clock throttled (total events = 25356)

Comment: Suggest you check the BIOS of this two year old machine for fan setting options. Also, have you cleaned the interior to make sure dust is not blocking the fan?

Comment: No there is no fan setting option in BIOS and i don't think this is a hardware issue because everything is fine on windows.

Comment: If you're getting clock throttling, the CPUs are too hot to reliably function unless they are slowed down.

Comment: But always when i plug in charger my logs says this..and the fans spin with loud sound.

Comment: Then your CPU is too hot.